# Change Icon when nuxt-link is active?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have 3 links in navbar and each link contains 2 icons (lets say icon-1 and icon-2), but i want to show only 1 icon at a time.

---

icon-1 when nuxt-link is active and hovered

---

icon-2 when nuxt-link is inactive

this is my code

```
     <ul>
        <li class="nav-list-item" v-for="(link, i) in navLinks" :key="i">
          <nuxt-link :to="link.path">
            <img :src="link.inactive"> //this is icon-1
            <img :src="link.active"> //this is icon-2
            <span class="nav-title">{{link.title}}</span>
          </nuxt-link>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

this is my script

```
data() {
    return {
      

      navLinks: [
        { 
          title: 'Link 1', 
          path: '/' , 
          inactive: './Icons/home-icon-1.svg', 
          active: './Icons/home-icon-2.svg'
        },
        { 
          title: Link 2', 
          path: '/about' , 
          inactive: './Icons/about-icon-1.svg', 
          active: './Icons/about-icon-2.svg'
        },
        { 
          title: 'link 3', 
          path: '/contact' , 
          inactive: './Icons/contact-icon-1.svg', 
          active: './Icons/contact-icon-2.svg'
        },
        
      ]
    }
  },
```

Comment: Pretty similar to that one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72836503/8816585

Comment: @kissu but how to change icon when link is active

Comment: What did you tried so far? Did you tried what I've suggested in your previous question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to set active state in every link object:

```
    {
      title: 'Link 1',
      path: '/',
      inactive: './Icons/home-icon-1.svg',
      active: './Icons/home-icon-2.svg',
      isActive: false,
    },
```

then you must set two native event listeners on nuxt link and logic to show img:

```
<nuxt-link
    :to="link.path"
    @mouseover.native="link.isActive = true"
    @mouseleave.native="link.isActive = false"
  >
    <img v-if="link.isActive"
          :src="link.inactive">
    <img v-else
      :src="link.active">
    <span class="nav-title">{{ link.title }}</span>
</nuxt-link>
```

Comment: also you can set class (looks like "is-active" or the same) on nuxt link and set display: none  css property to one of your image when nuxt class 'is-active'  true or false.